# SQL Server: array of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Ok I have been pondering the idea of dynamic columns, what I mean by this is a table of columns named `January`......`December`.

User at runtime would select a month **range** such as `Feb` to `July`.

What I would normally do is fetch all columns from my code behind then sort the ones I need and ones I don't.

But I was wondering a way to do this all in SQL.

I know SQL doesn't support arrays (*sad face*) but there are alternatives.

So my question is, is there a way for a SQL query to be set-up that **dynamically selects** a number of **columns** depending on a parameter that is a range of column names?

I've looked at some dynamic query's, but they only do 1 column.

I'm thinking along the lines of passing a **string of columns** provided by the code behind as 1 param in the SQL, then somehow iterate through to select each column.

What do you guys think? cant be Done? can be done but messy?

EDIT: thought I would provide some code, as you can see I apply a pivot query and get a range of columns (months). What's being suggested so far is to normalise first then pivot.

```
SELECT
   [1] January ,
   [2] February,
   [3] March,
   [4] April,
   [5] May,
   [6] June,
   [7] July,
   [8] August,
   [9] September,
   [10] October,
   [11] November,
   [12] December
   FROM
(
  SELECT MONTH(Convert(datetime,[lasttaken],120)) as months, complete
  FROM #Temp WITH(NOLOCK)
) d
pivot 
(
   count(complete)
   for months in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) p
```

Comment: yes. question is a bit off topic

Comment: eh? how is it off topic?

Comment: it's an open discussion question

Comment: not sure what you mean, im not asking for opinions, im asking for solutions. i.e one answer is to normalise before i get to this stage then use a pivot query after. I fail to see how this is a bad question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to do this, but involves restructuring your table.
Your problem is that the (month) column names are [meta data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata), and you want to see them

Instead of

```
year | Jan | feb | Mar | Apr | etc  
2013 | 10  | 9   | 11  | 4   | 0
```

as actual data.

What you want to do is make a column for month, and [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data to look like this.

```
year | month | data
2013 | 1     | 10
2013 | 2     | 9
2013 | 3     | 11
2013 | 4     | 4
```

Now you can query the data by month.

This is how you have to approach data design to be able to query the data the way you want to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeh coming to realize this now, ill provide some code, the code provided is a pivot query that gets all months from the lasttaken date.  Whats being suggested is that before this i need to normalise and then pivot to achieve the result?

Comment: @Steven: Yes, thats pretty much it. How you need to store it and how you need to present it are two very different things.

Comment: yes seems I was focused on presentation rather than how it should be normalized, great answer as are the rest!

Answer (score 3):

And what is the problem with storing data in a normalized form -- a separate row for each month?  Then, when you want to fetch a particular range, just use the `where` clause.

SQL Server offers the `pivot` functionality, which makes it pretty easy to put row values into columns.

Answer (score 0):

you can create dynamic sql statement with required columns by passing it to `EXECUTE(@query)` statement.
for example

```
Execute ('select Jan, Feb, Mar from Table')
```

as suggested by others you need to normalize your table and then do where clause to select records for specific period.